# Speex encoding in Java

Tags: java, audio, jspeex

I have a .wav file and I am using [JSpeex](http://jspeex.sourceforge.net/) (latest version, i.e., 0.9.7) to encode it, but the encoding is not happening properly if anybody has worked on the file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From [here](http://lists.apple.com/archives/java-dev/2006/May/msg00470.html)

You can find the following snippet:

When I used a different output-file format, specifically the .spx suffix,
the encoding worked, and so did the subsequent decoding.  The final decoded
PCM WAV file then played successfully in QuickTime Player.

The original PCM WAV file I started with was "1-welcome.wav" from Sun's
JavaSound demo program.  If you installed Developer Tools, it's at:
/Developer/Examples/Java/Sound/JavaSoundDemo/audio/

The encoding command-line:

```
java -cp jspeex.jar JSpeexEnc -w --verbose 1-welcome.wav welcome.spx
```

Because it's 11 KHz, you have to encode using '-w' (wideband), or it will
fail with an obscure exception.

The decoding command-line:

```
java -cp jspeex.jar JSpeexDec --verbose welcome.spx welcome-pcm.wav
```

You can read the whole page at the link provided for more info.

Hope this solves your problem.